# Unit testing a custom control in a windows store project

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, ui-testing

I want to unit test the custom controls I create for a windows store project. Just simple things like "there is a button when X is true".

However, I can't seem to even instantiate the controls in a testing context. Whenever I try to invoke the constructor, I get an exception related to not being run in the UI context. I've also been unable to create coded UI test projects that target windows store projects.

- How do I programmatically instantiate a control to test? How do I create a WinRT UI synchronization context?
- How do I programmatically send "user" command events to a control?
- How do I programmatically instantiate/teardown the entire application?

Answer (score 1):

I've found a hacky way to make non-interactive parts work: with the function `Windows.ApplicationModel.Core.CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.RunAsync`.

Obvious, right? However, this still leaves open the question of how to emulate user actions.

```cs
/// Runs an action on the UI thread, and blocks on the result
private static void Ui(Action action) {
    Windows.ApplicationModel.Core.CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.RunAsync(
        CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, 
        () => action()
    ).AsTask().Wait();
}
/// Evaluates a function on the UI thread, and blocks on the result
private static T Ui<T>(Func<T> action) {
    var result = default(T);
    Ui(() => { result = action(); });
    return result;
}
[TestMethod]
public void SliderTest() {
    // constructing a Slider control is only allowed on the UI thread, so wrap it in UI
    var slider = Ui(() => new Slider());
    var expected = 0;
    // accessing control properties is only allowed on the UI thread, so same deal
    Assert.AreEqual(expected, Ui(() => slider.Value));
}
```